# Do I need SQS queues to store remote data in the Amazon Web Services (AWS) cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

My first question is, do I need SQS queues to receive my remote data, or can it go directly into an Amazon cloud storage solution like S3 or EC2?

Currently, my company uses a third-party vendor to gather and report on our remote data. By remote data, I mean data coming from our machines out in the wilderness. These data are uploaded a few times each day to Amazon Web Services SQS queues (setup by the third party vendor), and then the third-party vendor polls the data from the queues, removing it and saving it in their own on-premises databases for one year only. This company only provides reporting services to us, so they don't need to store the data long-term.

Going forward, we want to own the data and store it permanently in Amazon Web Services (AWS). Then we want to use machine learning to monitor the data and report any potential problems with the machines.

To repeat my first question, do we need SQS queues to receive this data, or can it go directly into an Amazon cloud storage solution like S3 or EC2?

My second question is, can an SQS queue send data to two different places? That is, can the queue send the data to the third party vendor, and also to an Amazon Web Services database?

I am an analyst/data scientist, so I know how to use the data once it's in a database. I just don't know the best way of getting it into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to have a queue. Whenever you push an item in Queue a function gets triggered and you can perform your custom logic in that. whether you want to store the information to S3/EC2 or sending it to anyother Http service.

Your Lambda(function) can send the data to anyother 3rd party service easily.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that AWS Lambda (serverless compute) is a substitute for SQS queues, and I can use AWS Lambda to receive teh remote data instead?

Comment: you are welcome Sean,
1. answer is yes, this would reduce your cost, as you don't have to pay for SQS
2. why don't you just put data to S3 directly? and put a trigger on S3 to publish that data to 3rd party. you have nothing to worry about in this manner.

Comment: I love your suggestion about putting my data in S3 directly. I wondered about that. Our reason for using SQS is that our data stays in the queue even if the third-party vendor's on-premises server goes down. But Amazon S3 shouldn't need a queue at all, in my rookie opinion. I was actually hoping that someone would suggest that! :D

Comment: I asked a related question here if you're interested in answering that one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268546/does-amazon-web-services-aws-lambda-support-all-python-libraries

Comment: @Sean_Calgary see also [What is a Message Queue?](https://aws.amazon.com/message-queue/) in the AWS docs.