# Does Amazon Web Services (AWS) Lambda support all Python libraries?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

For example, I would like to use scikit-learn for machine learning, and pandas, numpy, and matplotlib/seaborn for data analysis. Does AWS Lambda support all these libraries? Is there a list of libraries supported? Or should I create a virtual server instead, to ensure I can use any Python library I want?

Comment: If you end up using an EC2 instance, the Amazon ML AMI image contains the drivers etc for Nvidia CUDA support for ML, plus several Python packages; this is relevant for the g3/g4/g5/p3 etc types

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those modules are not available by default. I found this (older) list of available modules, along with code to generate a current report of what is available, should you wish to do so:

https://gist.github.com/sjehutch/36493ff674b1b9a16fc44a5fc270760c

You can build your own environment using a virtualenv and upload that to Lambda. It can contain anything you want. See here for more info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

So you can still use AWS Lambda, and should not require a virtual server.

**Edited** to add a bit of self promotion:

I made a [web site that shows the current modules available in each environment provided by Amazon.](https://insidelambda.com/)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the default Python Standard Library, some third-party packages are embedded in AWS Lambda Python runtimes. These packages are ready to be used in your FaaS functions.

- Python    3.8.1
- boto3 1.10.34
- botocore  1.13.34
- docutils  0.15.2
- jmespath  0.9.4
- pip   19.2.3
- python-dateutil   2.8.0
- rapid-client  0.0.0
- s3transfer    0.2.1
- setuptools    41.2.0
- six   1.13.0
- urllib3   1.25.7

A daily-updated list of supported packages can be found here.
https://www.feitsui.com/en/article/2

Answer (score 1):

I've built a small library called [juniper](https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper) to automate the packaging of code for AWS lambda functions.

All you need to do to use juniper is create a small `manifest.yml` file that looks like:

```
functions:
  # Name the zip file you want juni to create
  router:
    # Where are your dependencies located?
    requirements: ./src/requirements.txt.
    # Your source code.
    include:
    - ./src/lambda_function.py
```

As long as you have your dependencies in the requirements.txt, juniper will package them for you. There are a few examples in our code base that showcase the features of juniper.

Comment: Cool man. I might give that a look next time I need to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @Pedro, your example `manifest.yml` has a comment that says "Name the zip file you want jui to create" but there is no associated name entry (unless "router" is that name !?). Could you please clarify that comment or update the example to demonstrate how to add the name?